SwiftUI duplicated border in Grid with blank tiles
Related to this: SwiftUI duplicated border in VStack/HStack
How can I avoid a duplicated border in a grid if I do not draw every single tile? The proposed solution seems to only work properly if all borders between tiles are drawn.

struct LeastQueensView: View {
    var tileList: [(Int, Int)] = [(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,1), (3,3), (3,4)]
    var maxX = 3
    var maxY = 4
    
    var body: some View {
        grid
    }
    
    var grid: some View {
        Grid(horizontalSpacing: 0, verticalSpacing: 0) {
            ForEach((1...maxX).reversed(), id: \.self) { i in
                GridRow {
                    ForEach(1...maxY, id: \.self) { j in
                        if tileList.contains(where: {$0 == (i,j)}) {
                            ZStack {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                                Rectangle()
                                    .strokeBorder(lineWidth: 1)
                                    .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            Rectangle()
                                .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

All borders in between grey tiles are doubled while borders adjacent to a white tile are not.

This is happening because you are using .strokeBorder to stroke the border of a square, which paints the border inside the frame of the view. This means, when two squares are in contact, the border has double-thickness.
If you change it to .stroke then the border is painted on the frame of the view. This means, when two squares are in contact, the borders overlap. However, this leads to a new problem, because the white squares will then paint over the half-border that is touching their edge.

To resolve this new problem, use .clear instead of .white to fill the blank squares.
You can also avoid the nested ZStack by filling and stroking the same shape.

ForEach(1...maxY, id: \.self) { j in
    if tileList.contains(where: {$0 == (i,j)}) {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.gray)
            .stroke(.primary, lineWidth: 1)
            .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
    }
    else {
        Color.clear
            .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}


